# How do I achieve the following xml layout?

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-drawable

**Layout made by me**

[image]

**Layout I want to achieve**

[image]

**orange_hollow_fill_round_corner.xml** (Custom Drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/orange" />

    <size
        android:width="80dp"
        android:height="20dp" />

</shape>
```

[image]

I want to make custom drawable like shown below so that the it does not cut *Earned Badges* Text view.

[image: made in paint]

Please ignore differences in corner and colors of *my layout* and *layout that I want to achieve*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it by just add background to textView (Earned Badges) this background has corner and black color by `android:background="@drawable/your_custom_button"` it will overlap on orange stork .

I hope it will help you .

Comment: background of text view has to be transparent so the image view that is applied to parent layout is visible

Comment: i see the image view black you can add background of text view black my bro .

Comment: My bad I did not recognize that the text view background is black. However, how do I make custom drawable like mentioned in last figure?

Answer (score 0):

As @noureldien mohamed way may seem viable for now but if you really want to create drawable like you mentioned you should try making vector .here is the one as per your liking.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:viewportWidth="326.33"
android:viewportHeight="76.25"
android:width="326.33dp"
android:height="76.25dp">
<path
    android:pathData="M201.13 2h109.2c7.7 0 14 6 14 13.25V61c0 7.29 -6.3 13.25 -14 13.25H16c-7.7 0 -14 -6 -14 -13.25V15.25C2 8 8.3 2 16 2h92.42"
    android:strokeColor="#FC7F2D"
    android:strokeWidth="3"
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round" />
```

***OUTPUT***

[image]